# QGIS Select By Location geometric predicates explanations?

Tags: qgis, select-by-location, documentation

Im trying to test if a polygon either a) touches or b) is only semi-contained by another polygon. The first is self-explanatory i guess, but the second could be many of the different predicates offered in QGIS.

I was therefore wondering if there are any more indepth explanations of the geometric predicates used in QGIS' select by location. (the only slightly basic explanation is [Documentation "Join Attributes by Location" QGIS 2.18](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/documentation-join-attributes-by-location-qgis-2-18?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which doesn't give any real clue as to what the terms cover)

Answer (score 0):

This explanation of the Dimensionally Extended Nine-Intersection Model used by GEOS which is used by QGIS should provide the best explanation of the predicates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM