# Differentiate between line ending within polygon and line passing all the way through polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, overlapping-features, select-by-location

I have a line file and a polygon file in QGIS.

Primarily I am looking for any polygon that has a line intersecting it - easy, sorted.

From these intersects, I then want to pull out just the polygons that have a line going all the way through them and ignore those where the line ends within the polygon. See the below diagram for an explanation: I only want polygons 2 and 3.

[image: Example]

Does that make sense? I haven't managed to find any predefined tools thus far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a possibility using a [**"Virtual Layer"**](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume we have two layers, namely  `'lines_test'` and `'polygons'`

[image: Input]

With using this query it is possible *to differentiate between line ending within polygon and line passing all the way through polygon.*

```sql
SELECT *
FROM polygons
WHERE polygons.id NOT IN (
    SELECT polygons.id
    FROM polygons, lines_test
    WHERE ST_Within(ST_StartPoint(lines_test.geometry), polygons.geometry)
          OR ST_Within(ST_EndPoint(lines_test.geometry), polygons.geometry)
)
```

[image: Output]

---

**References:**

- [PostGIS – Opposite of ST_Within](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35980155/5791355)
- [Chapter 8. PostGIS Reference | 8.5. Geometry Accessors](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html)
- [Understanding Join Attributes by Location in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/understanding-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis)