# Joining Attributes by Location to nearest point?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, proximity

I have a point feature and I want to perform a spatial join with the *nearest* point of another point feature (maybe even within a certain buffer distance). I know QGIS has a nice spatial join tool `"Join Attributes by Location"` and I figured out what the geometric predicates do from [Documentation "Join Attributes by Location" QGIS 2.18](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/).

However, there isn't an option *nearest*, although the QGIS API Documentation for the `QgsGeometry` class suggests that there is a class [nearestPoint()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a412e55ba03454baa52ec3dc49901baaa).

[image: Example]

Does anyone know how to perform this kind of analysis in QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use QGIS virtual layers with the following statement:

```sql
WITH closest_candidates AS (
     SELECT a.*, b.*, st_distance(a.geometry, b.geometry) as dist
     FROM a,b
     WHERE st_intersects(a.geometry, st_buffer(b.geometry,100))
)

SELECT *
FROM closest_candidates
WHERE dist < 50
```

this will perform a spatial join on the layers a and b within a buffer of 100 meters around b and then select the objects where the distance is lower than 50 meters. Be aware that virtual layers will be slow if you have a lot of items in your layer.

[image: Result]

Comment: Btw, do you know up to which number of features extend Virtual Layers work well ?

Comment: I worked with up to 5000 within one query, which worked. but sometimes it is better to save the virtuallayer to a real layer and continue with that layer...

Comment: I did as you suggested, but the virtual layer won't show any features on the map. The attribute table lets me know that the join worked (merged the column names), but [the fields are empty](https://imgur.com/YqJRht3). Btw I'll have probably a million point features...I need to check how virtual layers work, I have never worked with those before tbh.

Comment: @GeoEki, then your solution is probably PyGIS

Answer (score 2):

Qgis 3.8 has an inbuilt algorithm to join to nearest features (you could download a nightly prerelease to use this before the final 3.8 release next month)

Comment: you're right, [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/3637) is exactly what I need, thank you. I'll give it a try this weekend and report back here if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not upgraded to QGIS 3.8, you can use the NNJoin Plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/ http://arken.nmbu.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/NNJoin/). It is available through the official QGIS plugin repo.