# Information of two attribute tables together in one

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-joins

I need the information of a layer with track points (X and Y coordinates) and the information of a polygon layer (area) together in one layer. The problem is that the two attribute tables have no column or description in common, but I need the polygons and the trackpoints which create the outline of the polygon, in one Excel sheet.

Is there a chance to bring those layers together in one?

Comment: do they have any data in common?

Comment: No they don't have any data in common. So this won't work then right?

Answer (score 5):

If your track points compose the outline of the polygon, it means that they share a spatial relationship. Thus, you could use the Join Attributes by Location tool. Here you specify the type of spatial relationship between the input layer and the join layer. In QGIS3 the tool is located in Vector > Data Management Tools and its  interface look like this:

[image]

Here is a very nice [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/305193/86131) describing each type of spatial relation.