# Merge connecting lines which have the same attributes?

Tags: qgis, merge

In QGIS, there is a road map shape file, and I would like merge connecting lines which have the same attributums ("name" and "fclass").

I tried the "Dissolve" processing tool, but it doest't care about the geometry (it merges those lines which are not connecting, too). Can I split those which are not connencting?

Comment: Try 'Selecting by location' ([choose geometric predicates wisely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/understanding-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis/305193#305193), e.g. intersects will do the work) from your layer by intersecting it with itself and then over the selected features apply dissolve by `"name"` and `"fclass"`.

Comment: Or you could run `multi to singlepart` after you dissolved your lines based on said attributes.