# Extracting polygons that overlay other polygons in different layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, overlapping-features, select-by-location

I have two polygon layers that have multiple polygons in them. One layer is an administrative boundary layer and the other is a layer showing crop cover types. I would like to extract only administrative boundaries that have the certain crop type within them. Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

Another approach using the ["Extract by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-location) with *'intersect'* as geometric predicate, see image below.

[image: extract_by_location]

To get more familiar with geometric predicates, please check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/understanding-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis/305193#305193).

Comment: (First you need to select the "certain crop types", then check "Selected features only, if I understand the question correct)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use one of these functions in Vector -> Geoprocessing Tool
[image]

Comment: IMHO the *'Intersection'* geoalgorithm from the Processing Toolbox may suit the best way, please find more in the [QGIS Docs | Vector overlay](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#vector-overlay).