# Select lines in within a polygon (buffer) with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, within

I have one polygon layer "polygons" and one line layer "lines". I would like to create a layer with all line parts that are inside the polygon layer.
First I cut the lines in the intersection of the polygon layer. I can see that all lines are cut in the intersection of the polygons.
then I would like to select the line parts inside the polygon that has a length longer than approximate the double width of the polygon (buffer).
First image shows the cutted lines, I've highlighted one line for you to see. the black area is the polygons (buffer).

[image: cutted lines in the black polygon, one highlighted]

I use the following sql to select the "inside"-lines:

```
CREATE TABLE public."insidelines" AS SELECT l.*
    FROM "lines" l
        LEFT JOIN "polygons" p ON ST_Contains(p.the_geom, l.the_geom)
    WHERE p.the_geom IS NOT NULL AND ST_Length(l.the_geom) > 2000;

 ALTER TABLE public."insidelines" ALTER COLUMN the_geom TYPE geometry(LINESTRING, 32633) USING ST_SetSRID(the_geom, 32633);
```

the result is:

[image: result]

It is only the yellow line that was found! Any idea why?

Both layers are in UTM 33 (32633).
I'm using PostGIS ver 2.5

Comment: `contains` in this case is wrong, because *the line geometry is NOT completely (somehow and somewhere) contained into the polygon one*. You can try `touches` or `within` instead

Comment: It is the same result with st_within, st_touches will find any line outside or inside that touches the polygon/polygon border.

Comment: Please check this for more details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/understanding-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis/305193#305193

Comment: The thick red line is not fully contained in the black polygon (see lower left). Also don't forget that you are excluding segments shorter than 2km, so check whether the line you think should be selected is indeed a single segment or multiple segments that are too short

Comment: Hmm, se TRUE (PLOYGON/LINESTRING) example on https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html. The line is on the border of the Polygon. Since I cut the lines with the black polygon the end- or if it is the start-point is on the border and the rest is inside the polygon. Should not that apply with the link above? The Linestring in this example is way longer tha 2000m.

Comment: The yellow line in picture 2 is also cut by the black polygon and this is found.

Comment: Ah, I see, the cutting is likely the issue then (due to rounding, grid snapping, the point is not exactly on the polygon border). You can try adding a vertex to the polygon at the intersection point + do a snapToGrid on both the cut lines and the polygons after the cut. Alternatively, it may be (much) simpler to just select lines whose center point is within the polygons, or to apply a very small buffer to the black polygons

Comment: Centerpoint! Clever!

Comment: Why cutting the lines? Just get the `ST_Intersection` and filter them directly for your desired length.