# Clipping vector layer with preserving boundaries of polygons in QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, clip, overlapping-features, boundaries

I would like to clip a vector layer containing buildings by a rectangular boundary (also a vector layer). However, rather than cutting straight through the buildings at the boundary, I want it to remove buildings that are fully outside the boundary. Meaning the clipping result I would like is in a jagged boundary, rather than a clean trim.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool you want is called '[extract by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-location)'. You can access it by typing in the search bar in the bottom left hand corner.

Then fill out the form with your buildings layer as `extract features from` layer and the boundary as the `By comparing to the features from` layer.

you probably want `intersect` as your predicate -see the [docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-location) for more on what they mean.

Answer (score 3):

Use the ["Extract by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-location) with either *intersect* or *overlap* predicate.

For more details check the [Understanding Join Attributes by Location in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/understanding-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis)