# Adding/concatenating multiple values in column when using line intersections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, vector, line, overlapping-features

I want to use the "Line Intersection" function in QGIS to create points wherever lines cross. The lines are roads and I need the road names in my points layer.

Does anyone have an idea how I can add the street name of each line to the point layer without creating points twice? The street names are in the input layer (osm roads).

The first image shows what it looks like when I use the line intersection feature. I have 12 point features for the same intersection. The second image shows how it should be. The other data is not important for me.

Not what I want:
[image]

That's how it should be:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) with this expression:

```
array_to_string(
  array_sort(
    array_distinct(
        overlay_touches(
            layer:='lines_layer_name', --specify the name of your line layer 
            expression:="name_2") --specify the targeting field
        )
    )
)
```

This expression utilizes the following functions: [`array_sort()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-sort), [`array_distinct()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-distinct), and [`overlay_touches()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-touches).

---

**References:**

- [Understanding Join Attributes by Location in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/understanding-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis/305193#305193)

Comment: Thank you very much! I worked with a short addition:

array_to_string(
 array_sort(
  array_distinct(
   overlay_touches(
    layer:='Test_osm', --specify the name of your line layer 
    expression:="name") --specify the targeting field
        )
    )
)