# Summing values of different layers based on another

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, spatial-join, summarizing

I have a layer (called here 'layer_top') made of multiple polygons (in orange in the picture). Each polygon of the 'layer_top' overlaps with polygons of other different layers (called here 1,2,3,...). Each of these layers, within the 'layer_top', has a column with a score value (like in the picture). I would like to get the sum of the scores of all polygons of the layers 1,2,3, ... contained in each polygon of the layer_top.
I have searched for a solution in this forum and tried to join attributes by location (including summary), but the result is not what I want.
[image]
[image]

Comment: are there any preferences regarding the geometric predicate between polygons e.g. they must be fully inside or partial overlap is also allowed ? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/understanding-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis/305193#305193

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Fully inside

Comment: See my answer. Depending on the number of layers you have in your project, their name as well as the name of the attributes, you could use `array_foreach()` function to avoid repeating the same part over and over again. If interested, please provide information about the number of layers, their names and name of attributes.

Comment: thank you. Where do you use that function? in the field calculator of the 'layer_top'?  the number of layers within each polygon of the 'layer_top' are different (range between zero and ten). The name of the attributes are different except for the name of the score column

Comment: Ok, then probably indeed naming layers and attribute field manually is the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this question: transform all layers in raster and then sum the values with  r.series of GRASS. Easy!

Answer (score 4):

Use QGIS expressions with [`overlay_contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-contains). Use this expression where score1-3 are the names of the attribute you want to get the sum from:

```
array_sum (overlay_contains ('layer1', score1)) +
array_sum (overlay_contains ('layer2', score2)) +
array_sum (overlay_contains ('layer3', score3))
```

Comment: Thank you. Where do you use that function? in the field calculator of the 'layer_top'?

Comment: Yes, exactly there!

Comment: It says invalid expression. I think this is also time-consuming. What if I create a raster above the layers 1,2,3... and I calculate the highest score under each pixel? I mean I want to assign to each pixel the score of the layer below it that has the maximum value. How can I do that eventually?